# How can I get the values of hash using a key array?

Tags: ruby

I want to get all value of a hash using an array containing the keys?

I have this hash:

```
{:id=>402, :email=>"tyson@ledner.name", :organizations_count=>0, :username=>"admin"}
```

I have an array :

```
[:id, :email]
```

So I want to get an array of

```
["402", "tyson@ledner.name"]
```

Is there a cleaver way to do this? I have a loop but I feel ruby can do this in a "oneliner" way but can figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `Hash#values_at`:

```
hash = {:id=>402, :email=>"tyson@ledner.name", :organizations_count=>0, :username=>"admin"}
array = [:id, :email]
hash.values_at(*array)
#=> [402, "tyson@ledner.name"]
```

Passing array with splat operator (*) as argument in this case is same as just `hash.values_at(:id, :email)`

Comment: Did not find this easily, I'll try